# notifications not loading in my rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, notifications

I have a rails app that allows users to comment on a certain task, and each time a comment is posted on a task, the users who follow that project should get a notification.  My ajax notifications don't pop up when I click on the notifications icon:

notifications.js.coffee

```
class Notifications
    constructor: ->
        @notifications = $("[data-behavior='notifications']")
        @setup() if @notifications.length >0

    setup: ->
        $.ajax(
            url: "/notifications.json"
            dataType: "JSON"
            method: "GET"
            success: @handleSuccess
        )

    handleSuccess: (data) =>
        items = $.map data, (notification) ->
            "<a class='dropdown-item' href="#">#{notification.actor} #{notification.action} #{nofication.notifiable.type}</a>"
        $("[data-behavior='notification-items']").html(items)

jQuery ->
    new Notifications
```

_navigation_links.html.erb partial (where my notifications icon is held)

```
<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user white"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li><%= link_to "start a project", new_project_path %></li>

        <% if user_signed_in? %>

        <li class="nav-item btn-group" data-behavior="notifications">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="fa">
                <%= fa_icon "bell" %>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" data-behavior="notification-items">

            </div>
        </li>

        <div class="dropdown" style="float: right; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 15px;">
          <li class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" style="cursor: pointer;">
           <%= current_user.username %>
           <span class="caret"></span>
          </li>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                <li><%= link_to 'My Profile',  users_following_user_path(current_user) %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Edit Profile', profile_user_path(current_user) %></li>
                <li><%= link_to 'Account Settings', edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><%= link_to 'Log out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <% elsif %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path %></li>
        <% end %>

    </ul>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :notifications
```

notification.rb Model

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :actor, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :notifiable, polymorphic: true

  scope :unread, -> { where(read_at: nil) }
end
```

From the couple tutorials i've been following, the notifications should pop up when i click the bell icon in the navigation links.  The javascript is not working however...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are typos in the `notifications.js.coffee` file, please change the handleSuccess function to the following (change `href="#"` to `href='#'`):

```
handleSuccess: (data) =>
    items = $.map data, (notification) ->
        "<a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>#{notification.actor} #{notification.action} #{nofication.notifiable.type}</a>"
    $("[data-behavior='notification-items']").html(items)
```

This should fix the issue.